# Need regex for a string having characters followed by even number of digits

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone tell how I can write regex for a string that take one or more alphanumeric character followed by an even number of digits?

Valid:

```
a11a1121
bbbb11a1121
```

Invalid:

```
a11a1
```

I have tried `^[a-zA-Z*20-9]*$` but it is always giving true.

Can you please help in this regard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex that you have mentioned will search for any number of [either a-z, or A-Z or 2 or 0-9]

You can break down your requirement to groups and then  handle it accordingly.

Like you require at least one character. so you start with `^([a-zA-Z]+)$`

Then you need numbers in the multiple of 2. so you add `^([a-zA-Z]+(\d\d)+)$`

Now you need any number of combination of these. So the exp becomes: `^([a-zA-Z]+(\d\d)+)*$`

You can use online tools like [regex101](https://regex101.com) for these purpose. The provided regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/MnWDhI/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with this regexp: `^[a-z0-9]*[a-z]+([0-9]{2})*$`

Explanation :

- `[a-z0-9]*[a-z]+`: a string of at least one character terminated by a non digit one
- `([0-9]{2})*`: an odd sequence of digits (0 or 2*n digits). If the even sequence cannot be null, use `([0-9]{2})+` instead.